# How to set prediction threshold in Keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I’m trained a model with Keras to do a binary classification task with 0 and 1 labels, and I tested it on a series of images. Some of these images are very similar and were predicted as 1, so I want to know is there a way to set some threshold or scores to sort out the images that most likely to be 1 in Keras?

Answer (score 2):

if you are performing semantic segmentation then carry out the below method

perform

```
image = model.predict(your_input_image)
_,height,width,_ = image.shape()
image = image.reshape(height,width)
image[image >= threshold_percentage] = 255
image[image < threshold_percentage] = 0
```

if normal binary

```
result = model.predict(your_input_image)
if result[0][1] > threshold_percentage:
    #belongs to class 1
else:
    #belongs to class 2
```

Comment: What happens if there is neither of the two classes, it will yield a false prediction right???

Comment: The output will always belong to one or the other class, for instance in case of binary you train your model with fore foreground and background and for multi class you have a background class which contains all other irrelevant classes which you don’t want to train